# Why is the paint() method not executing update() or paint() methods?

Tags: java, awt, doublebuffered

I'm having this problem where the *paint()* or *update()* methods in a class isn't getting called when I execute *repaint()*. Here's the code:

```
public class BufferedDisplay extends Canvas implements Runnable {

// Contains all the images in order, ordered from background to foreground
private ArrayList<ImageStruct> images;
// Tracks the last insert ID of the last image for a particular layer
private TreeMap<Integer, Integer> insertIDs;
// Image that holds the buffered Image
private Image offscreen;

public BufferedDisplay() {
    images = new ArrayList<ImageStruct>();
    insertIDs = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
}

public void addImageStruct(ImageStruct is) {
    int layer = is.getLayer();
    // Index to insert the image at
    int index = -1;
    if(insertIDs.containsKey(layer)) {
        index = insertIDs.get(layer)+1;
        insertIDs.put(layer, index);
    }
    else {
        index = images.size();
        insertIDs.put(layer, index);
    }
    if(index>-1) {
        images.add(index, is);
    }
}

public void run() {
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("\nSleeping... ");
            System.out.print("ArraySize:"+images.size()+" ");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print("Slept. ");
            repaint();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Display Error: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}

// Overrides method so the background isn't automatically cleared
public void update( Graphics g )
{
    System.out.print("Updating... ");
    paint(g);
}

public void paint( Graphics g )
{
    System.out.print("Painting... ");
    if(offscreen == null)
        offscreen = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
    Graphics buffer = offscreen.getGraphics();
    buffer.setClip(0,0,getSize().width, getSize().height);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    paintImages(buffer);
    g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, null);
    buffer.dispose();
}

public void paintImages( Graphics window )
{
    for(ImageStruct i : images) {
        i.draw(window);
    }
}
}
```

This class is implemented in this:

```
public class Game extends JPanel{
// A reference to the C4Game class
private C4Game game;
// A reference to the BufferedDisplay class
private BufferedDisplay display;
// The Image used to initialize the game board
private Image tile;
private int tileSize = 75;
private int tileLayer = 5;
// Thread that controls animation for the BufferedDisplay
Thread animation;

public Game(C4Game game) {
    this.game = game;
    display = new BufferedDisplay();
    try {
        tile = ImageIO.read(new File("img\\tile.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ((Component)display).setFocusable(true);
    add(display);
    animation = new Thread(display);
    animation.start();
    initBoard();
}

public void initBoard() {
    for(int x = 0; x<game.numRows()*tileSize; x+=tileSize) {
        for(int y = 0; y<game.numCols()*tileSize; y+=tileSize)  {
            System.out.println("Placing " +x +" " +y +"...");
            display.addImageStruct(new ImageStruct(tile, tileLayer, x, y, tileSize, tileSize));
        }
    }
}
}
```

...Which is then implemented in a JFrame.

```
public class TetraConnect extends JFrame{

    public TetraConnect() {
    super("TetraConnect", 800, 600);
    try {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("img/icon.png"));
        ms = new MainScreen(this);
        add(ms);
        ms.updateUI();
        C4Game c4g = new C4Game(5,6);
        Game g = new Game(c4g);
        add(g);
        g.updateUI();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Init. Error: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

The output when I run it, is:

```
Slept.
Sleeping... Slept.
Sleeping... Slept.
Sleeping... Slept.
```

And so forth. I'm also not able to see any images on the Canvas (I'm assuming they are never drawn in the first place). It seems to completely skip the repaint method; the debug statements     "Updating... " and     "Repainting... " never show up. However, repaint also seems to be executing; the loop repeats without problems. Why isn't the repaint method calling the paint() or update() methods?

Comment: You have posted a lot of code now, however your code is still not "self-contained" (nobody can try to compile and run it), and does not show how the panel is added to the top-level container (frmae). I suggest you try to reduce this to a complete example that is self-contained, but also as simple as possible.

Comment: Please use the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: @Grodriguez Alright, I think I get what you're saying now. Sorry for misunderstanding :x @Ishtar Why? I don't see any reason to... Is it good practice to?

Comment: Mixing lightweight components (JFrame, JPanel) and heavyweight components (Canvas) is likely to give you some headaches. I would recommend to either stick with AWT and use only heavyweights, or fully move to Swing and use only lightweights. Anyway I take it your problem is solved now?

Comment: @Grodriguez Yes it is, but thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @camickr noted in the comments, you are using the heavyweight AWT canvas.  You should really be using lightweight Swing components.  Instead of:

```
public class BufferedDisplay extends Canvas implements Runnable {
```

I recommend:

```
 public class BufferedDisplay extends JPanel implements Runnable {
```

Given that small change, I would then do the following:

When overriding the default paining of a component you should override the paintComponent() method.

So, instead of:

```
public void paint( Graphics g )
{
```

It should be:

```
protected void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
```

That may fix your problem.

Also, you shouldn't have to override the `update()` method.  Instead, just leave out a call to `super.paintCompenent(g)` in the paint component method.  This should cause the background to be left alone by default.

Comment: Your suggestion is valid for Swing components. So you would also need to add the suggestion to use a JPanel instead of a Canvas. That would also be my advice to the poster. Use Swing instead of AWT.

Comment: @cam, I completely missed that the OP was using `Canvas`.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Switching from AWT to Swing will not magically fix the OP's problem. Even though Swing might be a better option in most situations, there's no reason why he shouldn't be able to do what he wants to do using AWT alone.

Comment: @Grod, agreed.  It is usually best practices to use Swing components though.  And, I know it won't magically fix the OP's problem.  That's why I suggested a few more things after I suggest using light weight components.

Comment: @jjnguy: Yes, but your other suggestions (overriding paintComponent instead of paint, and not overriding update) are part of the "switch to lightweight components" bit. None of that is necessary if he does not switch to Swing (which also means, none of that is actually the cause of his problem in the first place).

Comment: @Grod, I have no argument to your points.  All I can do is reiterate that he *should* be using Swing.  But, you are right.  My answer doesn't solve his problem if he doesn't switch to Swing.

Comment: :-) I don't want to be a pain, but I think you are missing my point. What I am saying is that your answer will not solve his problem *even if he switches to Swing*, because all the suggestions you make are about how to go from "correct AWT code" to "correct Swing code". However there is obviously some problem in the OP's original code (probably in the part he's not showing), so chances are this problem will remain there regardless of whether he follows your advice and switches to Swing.

Comment: @Grod, no worries.  However, I do feel that my Swing related suggestions would get the OP closer to solving his problem.  I do see what you mean though.  I cannot be sure that my answer will actually solve his problem.

Comment: ... and I think, due to your suggestions, it would be more sensible to switch to swing.

Comment: @DDP, I see you are placing the `BufferedPanel` on a `JPanel`.  You shouldn't be mixing Swing and AWT components like that.  I really think you would benefit from using a JPanel instead of a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `BufferedDisplay` object has been added to a container (e.g. a `Frame`), and that the container itself is visible. If the component is not showing, then calls to `repaint()` will not result in `update()` being called.

This is just generic advice. If you post a [self-contained example](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) that can be compiled and run it will probably be easier to find out what is wrong.

Comment: However, even if the component is not visible, shouldn't paint() be called anyway?

Comment: No. If the component is not visible, `paint()` is not called in response to `repaint()` (this can easily be checked if you inspect the source code for `Component.repaint()`)